# extract a substring from clob in oracle

Tags: oracle, substring, database, clob

I have a clob with data

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><root available-locales="en_US" default-locale="en_US"><static-content language-id="en_US"><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript">
function change_case()
{
    alert("here...");
    document.form1.type.value=document.form1.type.value.toLowerCase();
}
</script>

<form name=form1 method=post action=''''>
<input type=text name=type value=''Enter USER ID'' onBlur="change_case();">
<input type=submit value=Submit> </form>
</form>]]></static-content></root>
```

I want to extract the line with the onblur attribute, in this case:

```
<input type=text name=type value=''Enter USER ID'' onblur="change_case();">
```

Comment: And how does this Javascript code related in any way to Oracle?

Comment: it is the text stored in CLOB of the table

Answer (score 12):

Tom Kyte say how get varchar2 from clob in SQL or PL/SQL code

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:367980988799

And when you have varchar2 you can use SUBSTR or REGEXP_SUBSTR function for extract the line.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/functions147.htm#i87066

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm

If you want to use SQL code, you can create this request

```
select col1, col2, func1(dbms_lob.substr( t.col_clob, 4000, 1 )) from table1 t
```

And in PL/SQL function "func1" you can do what you want with input string using SUBSTR or any other functions

Comment: substr will take string ,starting position and length as parameters  substr( string, start_position, length), In this case i can get the starting position by using instr function for <script> tag but the issue is how to extract the sub string only till </script> tag.

Comment: i cant use pl/sql, How can I extract the line with html fragment <script> ... </script> using DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR , I need to do it in a sql statement only ( no pl/sql )

Answer (score 1):

Subdivide your problem. You want to extract a line of text from your CLOB which contains a particular substring. I can think of two possible interpretations of your requirements:

**Option 1.**

1. Split the CLOB into a series of lines - e.g. split it by newline/carriage return characters if that's really what you meant by "line".
2. Check each line to see if it includes the substring, e.g. `onblur`. If it does, you have found your line.

**Option 2.**

If you don't actually mean the *line*, but you want the `<script>...</script>` html fragment, you can use similar logic:

1. Search for the first occurrence of `<script>`.
2. Search for the next occurrence of `</script>` after that point. Extract the substring from `<script>` to `</script>`.
3. Search the substring for `onblur`. If it is found, return the substring. Otherwise, find the next occurrence of `<script>`, go to step 2, rinse, repeat.

Comment: Let me put a direct question .  How can I extract the line with html fragment <script> ... </script> using DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR , I need to do it in a sql statement only ( no pl/sql )

Comment: What version are you on? `SUBSTR` works with CLOBs in 10g and 11g.

Comment: 10g, SUBSTR(str,pos,len), i need to do something like SUBSTR(str,pos,pos2) which is not supported :(

Comment: um, you do realise that len can be derived from pos2 and pos?

Comment: dbms.instr('script'>) gives the start position ie.. pos, i need to pos2 ie. </script> tag

Comment: `INSTR` accepts an optional 2nd parameter, the starting position for the search. You put in `pos+1` for the 2nd parameter to `INSTR` searching for `'</script>'`, and you've got the position of the end tag.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters Undelete my answer here but delete the other one!